# jQuery .ajax() calls the error function instead of success if the XHR response is an ArrayBuffer representing a JSON object with an error property

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**Context:** I'm trying to implement an ajax download with a progress bar and error handling. The front end makes a request to a backend which responds with either a file to download, or an error in the form of a JSON object.

**Problem:** I'm using a custom xhr, where the `responseType` is set to `arraybuffer`. This allows me to create a Blob for the file which I then use to present the download. If the backend responds with a JSON object, I can detect it properly, convert it to a string, and parse it into a native `Object`. However, if that `Object` contains a property called `error`, which I use throughout my application, jQuery calls `error()` rather than `success()`, and passes one parameter, the value of the `error` property.

What the heck is going on? I've set `dataType: false` to avoid any processing of data, but it seems that jQuery is parsing the arraybuffer, despite the `dataType` setting and the response header being set to `application/octet-stream`, and deciding that the object, having an error property, requires the `error()` function to be called.

How can I avoid this behavior without changing my backend? An alternate implementation could be to leave the `responseType` as text, and then turn the text into a Blob when its a file, but I could never get that to work properly.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "?download",
            method: "POST",
            data: {path: this.path, names: names},
            dataType: false,
            xhr: function() {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                myXhr.responseType = "arraybuffer"
                myXhr.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
                        var text = dir.formatSize(e.loaded, true) + "/" + dir.formatSize(e.total, true)
                        $("#dl-progress-bar").css("width", percent + "%");
                        $("#dl-progress-text").text(text)
                    }
                })
                return myXhr;
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#dl-progress").hide()
                $("#dl-progress-bar").css("width", "0")
                $("#dl-progress-text").html("&nbsp;")
                var bufView = new Uint8Array(data);
                //Check if the arraybuffer is actually JSON, starting with {"
                if (bufView[0] == 123 && bufView[1] == 34 && bufView.length < 200) {
                    var string = decodeURIComponent(escape(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.apply(bufView))))
                    try {
                        var json = JSON.parse(string)
                        if (json.success === false && json.error) {
                            this.error(json.error)
                            return
                        }
                    }
                    catch (e) {}
                }


                if (data != null && navigator.msSaveBlob)
                    return navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([data], { type: type }), name)
                var a = $("<a style='display: none;'/>")
                var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/octet-stream"})
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                a.attr("href", url)
                a.attr("download", filename)
                $("body").append(a)
                a[0].click()
                setTimeout(function() {
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                    a.remove()
                }, 0)
            },
            error: function(req, status, error) {
                debugger
                $("#dl-progress").hide()
                $("#dl-progress-bar").css("width", "0")
                $("#dl-progress-text").html("&nbsp;")
                this.ajaxError(req, status, error)
            }.bind(this)
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't `bind()` my success function, so it was calling `this.error()` of the xhr object.